# Find the current week or post week using new date in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how to find it is a current week or previous week using the timestamp? is it possible to find using moment js

```
const dateEnd = moment(1518331101107);
```

I need to write if condition if it is the current week I need to through the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the week of a timestamp:

```
moment(1518331101107).week()    // =>  7
```

Find the current week:

```
moment().week()
```

You can do you comparaison:

```
if(moment(1518331101107).week() == moment().week()){
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: thank for reply, I tried this is not coming correct, my week start with Monday and end with Sunday, my weekday is `7` right now I am getting `6` only